# Resetear inputs clonados

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy intentando que los elementos sean clonados sin ningún valor en sus inputs. Busqué guias en inglés y las intenté, pero no me estaría saliendo y la verdad no estaria entendiendo por qué. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row mt-4 mb-2" id="contenedor">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <h4 class="fw-bold pe-2">Autor/es</h4>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" id="agregar"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger d-none" type="button" id="borrar"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clonar">
        <div class="col mb-2">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" aria-label=".form-control-sm example" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="NyA1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let agregar = document.getElementById("agregar");
    let contenido = document.getElementById("contenedor");

    agregar.addEventListener("click", e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let clonado = document.querySelector(".clonar"); // Seleccionamos lo que vamos a clonar
        let clon = clonado.cloneNode(true); // Ya clonado el nodo, osea el div
        clon.find("input").val("");

        contenido.appendChild(clon).classList.remove("clonar"); // Adjuntamos un hijo al final de todo
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los métodos `.find()` y `.val()` no existen en Javascript, a menos que estés usando una librería como jQuery.

En lugar de `.find()` usa [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) que, para este caso, te va a devolver un objeto [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) y solo debes modificar la propiedad `value`:

```
clon.querySelector('input').value = '';
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó, pero tengo una duda, en caso de que quisiera agregar un input más y también resetearlo, lo haria con querySelectorAll, no? (osea eso resetearia todos los inputs del nodo, no?)

Comment: @MarceloSanchez, no, sigue siendo con `querySelector()` porque estás obteniendo solo un `input` dentro del elemento clonado y no en todo el documento.